# Siddhi Kafka source sometime produces two events for a single source event

Tags: apache-kafka, siddhi

I'm testing pattern locally in Siddhi tooling 5.1.2 deployed to Docker.

I've got Kafka topic with 7 events, which visible using other monitoring tools. I defined a source and store all events to rdbms. A query is very simple: `from my_stream select * insert into my_table;`
By some reason, in DB I see 17 records which are actually 7 pairs of identical events. There is no special configuration, no errors.

I've tried to `down && up` docker-compose with the tooling, changed group-id of the source. Sometimes changing of group-id helps, but the problem comes back.

I would expect only 7 events to be read and stored to DB.

Why could it produce duplicated events?

Comment: It would be better if you could provide the Siddhi app, so that we can check the Kafka Source configurtions as well as RDBMS store configurations. Furthermore, if you can DESC the table, that might help too.

Comment: Hi @Dilini 
I've found the dependency which I described here https://github.com/siddhi-io/siddhi-io-kafka/issues/130 
I cannot prepare the code sample. From one hand the code is big, from another, it's as simple as it is mentioned in Siddhi manual (documentation).

Comment: Hi Alexander, I have replied to https://github.com/siddhi-io/siddhi-io-kafka/issues/130